# Two conflicting long lived process managers

Tags: asynchronous, architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, distributed-system

Let assume we got two long lived process managers. Both sagas operates over 10 milion items for example. First saga adds something to each item. Second saga removes it from each item. Given both process managers need few minutes to complete its job if I run them simultaneously I get into troubles.

Part of those items would hold the value while rest of them not. The result is close to random actually and depends on command order that affect particular item. I wondered if redispatching "Remove" command in case of failure would solve the problem. I mean if you try remove non existing value you should wait for the first saga to add the value. But while process managers are working someone else may dispatch "Remove" or "Add" command. In such case my approach would fail.

How may I solve such problem? :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you would want the second saga to not run if the first saga is running (and presumably not run until some process which depends on whatever the first saga added being there).  So the apparent solution would be to have a component (could be a microservice, could also be a record in a strongly consistent datastore like zookeeper/etcd/consul) that gives permission for the sagas to start executing.  An example protocol might look like:

- Saga sends a message to the component identifying the saga and conveying the intention to start
- Component validates that no sagas might be running which would prevent this  saga from running
- Component responds with permission to start running
- Subsequent saga attempts result in rejection until the running saga tells the component it's OK to run the other saga

Assuming that this component is reliably durable, the failure mode to worry about is that permission is granted but this component never processes the message that the saga finished (causes of this could include the permission message not getting delivered/processed or the saga crashing).  No amount of acknowledgements or extra messages can solve this (it's basically the Two Generals' Problem).

A mitigation is to have this component (or something watching this component) alert if it seems that too much time has passed without saga completion.  Whatever/whoever is responsible for ensuring liveness would then investigate to see if the saga is still running and if none is running, inform the component that it's OK to run the other saga.  Note that this is not foolproof: it's quite possible for the decider in question to make what turns out to be the wrong decision.

Comment: thank you for your great answer. I took such solution into consideration but to be honest I do not really like it because of its blocking manner. It would be perfect to come up with solution allows anyone to perform own actions without the need of waiting. Maybe it is even mathemticaly impossible to achieve such thing or that mixed result of performing both sagas simultaneously is perfectly valid. I am not sure if from domain perspective such behavior make much of sense. I just instinctively feel pain it the face of necessity of blocking applicaton in async world :)

Comment: The constraint of the two sagas operating on the same objects managed by the same service is what makes this difficult.  It might be possible to have whatever needs the data added by the first saga work off its own view of the objects with the data always there (this would be the more CQRS approach).

Comment: @ayeo An extension of this approach would be to have the processes share the same consistent state, so when the user initiates bulk update it will add the operations to this shared document (effectually a custom command queue with priority logic) and start executing the commands, when the second user initates her bulk update, it will add the commands to the same queue (document) which will decide the order of the commands to be executed with respect to the expected outcome. This will still block, but only the individual commands, not the full process.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I need more context.  Whilst you don't say it explicitly, is the problem that the second saga tries to remove values that haven't been added by the first?

If that was true, a simple solution would be to just use a third state.

What I mean by that is to just more explicitly define and declare item state.  You currently seem to have two states `with value`, and `without value`, but nothing to indicate if an item is ready to be processed by the second saga because the first saga has already done it's work on the item in question.

So all that needs to happen is that the second saga keeps looking for items where:

```
(with_value == true & ready_for_saga2 == true)
```

`Ready_for_saga2` or "Saga 1 processing complete", whatever seems more appropriate in your context.

Comment: removing/adding data is just an example. Generally speaking I mean situation when two sagas affect same item and the final state of that item depends on command order. In more complex system it would be even hard to spot the problem - mutual influecne on agreggate may be subtle. I just would like to manage consistent state of set of items eventually.

Comment: If you need to process in a specific order then you can't have 2 independent processes, because it creates "race conditions" (there's lots written about that, should be easy to search).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the solution would vary based on which actual problem, we're trying to solve.

Say it's an inventory and **add** are items added to the inventory and **remove** are items requested for delivery. Then the order of commands does not matter that much because you could just process the request for delivery, when new items are added to the inventory.

This would lead to an aggregate root with two collections: Items and PendingOrders.

One process manager adds new inventory to Items - if any orders are pending, it will complete these orders in the same transaction and remove both the item and the order from the collections.

If the other process manager adds an order (tries to remove an item), it will either do it right away, if there's any items left - or it will add the order to the pending orders to be processed when new items arrive (and maybe notify someone about the delay, while we're at it).

This way we end up with the same state regardless of the order of commands, but the actual real-world-problem has great influence on the model chosen.

If we have other real world problems, we can make a model those too.

Let's say you have two users that each starts a process that bulk updates titles on inventory items. In this case you - and the users - have to decide how best to resolve this conflict - what will lead to the best real world outcome.

If you want consistency across all the items - **all or no items** should be updated by a single bulk update - I would embed this knowledge in a new model. Let's call it `UpdateTitlesProcesses`. We have only one instance of this model in the system. The state is shared between processes. This model is effectually a command queue, and when a user initiates the bulk operation, it adds all the commands to the queue and starts processing each item one at a time.

When the second user initiates another title update, the business logic in our models will reject this, as there's already another update started. Or if the experts say that the last write should win, then we ditch the remaining commands from the first process and add the new ones (and similarly we should decide what should happen if a user issues a single title update, not bulk - should it be rejected, prioritized or put on hold?).

So in short I'd say:

1. Make it clear which real world problem we are solving - and thus which conflict resolution outcome is best (probably a trade off, often also something that requires user interaction or notification).
2. Model this explicitly (where processes, actions and conflict handling are also part of the model).